# A/C Compressor Replacement

Tags: honda, civic, belt-tensioner

An irregular knocking sound began about a week ago in our 2000 Honda Civic.

The mechanic has told us that the Acc. Belt Tension Pulley needs to be replaced, and that this is related to the AC compressor in such a way that both should be replaced.  Something about the way they fit together, they said if we didn't replace them at the same time, we'd be back in the shop within a couple months.

My concern is that the AC compressor replacement is ~$500 on top of the rest of the work to be done.  The AC works fine in the car, pumping out cold air etc.  Does it really need to be replaced as well?

Comment: Is the noise coming from the compressor?  Or the tensioner?

Comment: I believe the tensioner.  We're getting a second opinion today, so we'll see if we get a similar answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are they both the originally installed parts? The only way this can be true is if at one point you installed a non-OEM part that altered the way they fit together. I have replaced plenty of belt driven parts, and never replaced any other items, unless they were altered at one point or another. The compressor is usually locked in place, so this is hard to believed.